# How to dynamically load a component from an object in state array?

Tags: reactjs

When I make a selection from the dropdown I saved the selected value to `type` then when I click the button I add an object to drums, I map over thee drums and based on the type I want to render the component with the same name.

Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-kowalevski-j29w3?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import uuid from "react-uuid";
import "./styles.css";

const Snare = () => {
  return <div>Snare</div>;
};

const Gong = () => {
  return <div>Gong</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [drums, setDrums] = useState([]);
  const [type, setType] = useState();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {drums.map((Drum, index) => (
        <Drum.type /> // Why cant I use `.type`?
      ))}
      <label>
        Drum type to add:
        <select onChange={e => setType(e.target.value)} value={type}>
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="Snare">Snare</option>
          <option value="Gong">Gong</option>
        </select>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setDrums([...drums,
              {
                id: uuid(),
                type
              }
            ]);
          }}
        >
          Add drum
        </button>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `Drum.type` is not a component but a string, you need to maintain a map of the string to component and then render it

```
const map = {
  Snare: Snare,
  Gong: Gong
};

export default function App() {
  const [drums, setDrums] = useState([]);
  const [type, setType] = useState();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {drums.map((Drum, index) => {
        const Component = map[Drum.type];
        return <Component key={index}/>;
      })}
      <label>
        Drum type to add:
        <select onChange={e => setType(e.target.value)} value={type}>
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="Snare">Snare</option>
          <option value="Gong">Gong</option>
        </select>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setDrums([
              ...drums,
              {
                id: uuid(),
                type
              }
            ]);
          }}
        >
          Add drum
        </button>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-haze-ufwlg?file=/src/App.js:200-1060)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `type` is  a string.

You could create a mapping to solve this and use [`React.createElement()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement).

Something like:

```
const mapping = {
  'Snare': Snare,
  'Gong': Gong
}

{ drums.map(({ type }, index) => (
    React.createElement(mapping[type], { key: index })
  ))
}
```